# Warning when UIAlertController: 0x7ff211650140 called in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I get this warning sometimes when calling `UIAlert`

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is
>   deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior
>   ()

```
code used:

    func alert (dictKey: String){
        print(dictKey)
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: promptsArr[dictKey], preferredStyle: .Alert )
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in

        }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        if self.presentedViewController == nil {
            delay(1.0){
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else {
            self.presentedViewController!
        }
```

Comment: Where and how are u calling this method?

Comment: From within this switch code:

func resultOfValidation (dictKey: String, tag: Int) {
  
  delay(0.3){
   switch dictKey {
   case "SendVeriCode": //SMS sent
    //Server code will have to search for previous entry of the cell no under different name
    _ = self.alert(dictKey)
    if (tag < 6){self.VerifyInput[tag + 2].becomeFirstResponder()}
   case "Cancel":
    _ = self.alert(dictKey)
    self.VerifyInput[tag - 1].text = ""
    self.VerifyInput[tag].text = ""
    self.VerifyInput[tag - 2].becomeFirstResponder()

Comment: Please add that code as well to the question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove `delay()`
2. Put the logic inside `self.presentedViewController`:
   *(no need to create the alert if it exists)*

   ```
   func alert (dictKey: String){
       if self.presentedViewController == nil {
           let alertController = UIAlertController(
               title: nil,
               message: promptsArr[dictKey],
               preferredStyle: .Alert )
           let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {
               (action) in
           }
           alertController.addAction(OKAction)

           self.presentViewController(
               alertController,
               animated: true,
               completion: nil)
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you will try it straight away.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks. The delay(1.0){  } called a very useful method for synchronising two simultaneous running processes could also be used to replace OK  in the code with a specific time delay for clearing the alert - refer to  /* A handy bit of code created by Matt Neuburg, author of a lot of books including
  iOS Programming Fundamentals with Swift (O'Reilly 2015).
  See his reply in Stack Overflow for details:
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift/24318861#24318861
  
 
  */
Where I got this from

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift/24318861#24318861 is a very different situation than what you may need here. `delay` is not in any way a reliable approach for sync. Look into `-performSelector:afterDelay`, semaphores or, if at all possible, simple completion block.

Comment: Thanks for that will have a look at these suggestions

Comment: Thanks for answers - hopefully my reformatting will remove the down vote